# Update Azure DevOps Pool using REST api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to update the Azure DevOps Pool size using Azure DevOps RESI API in Azure Pipeline task InvokeRESTAPI@1

[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

```
steps:
- task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
    serviceConnection: 'myGenericSrvConn'
    method: 'PATCH'
    headers: |
      {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AuthToken": "$(system.AccessToken)"
      }
    body: |
      {
       "size": 1
      }
    urlSuffix: '/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9?api-version=7.0'
    waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

`Azure Pipeline Task Log`

```
InvokeRESTAPI

View raw log

============================================================================== 
Task         : InvokeRESTAPI
Description  : Invoke a REST API as a part of your pipeline.
Version      : 1.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help URL     : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api
============================================================================== 

PATCH https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9?api-version=7.0
Request body: {
  "size": 1
}
                Response Code: 0
                Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Access Denied. Microsoft-hosted agent pools cannot be modified.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.AccessDeniedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi","typeKey":"AccessDeniedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. (type WebException)
```

I am able to do GET on same api and feeling missing some authentication or something wrong with my body block.

I am trying to update the Azure DevOps Pool from InvokeRESTAPI azure pipeline task.

Comment: The rest api can be used to update self-hosted agent pool but not Microsoft-Hosted agent pool.

Answer (score 0):

The response, *which you have quoted in your question*, tells you the answer:

> Access Denied. Microsoft-hosted agent pools cannot be modified

Comment: What I need to do for authentication to make the update possible?

Comment: Why do you think the update is possible at all?

Comment: Below MS documentation give me confidence that it's possible.

[MS DOCS: Pools - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#request-body) _

Comment: You can update [your own private agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues), yes, but not the microsoft-hosted agent pool.